# ios app crashes when showing actionSheet  on top of a modal view

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

I have an iOS app, that works fine, and shows a modal view

when the modal view is loaded and I call an action sheet, or a custom pop up, close and open the action sheet twice and it crashes,

if I show the same action sheet or pop up in a direct view controller, it seems fine,

so my question is, how to show the action sheet on top of the modal view but loaded on the original view controller?

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", @"Other Button 2", nil];

popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;

[popupQuery showInView:self.view];

[popupQuery release];
```

so how to i show my action sheet in the main [parent] view controller and not in the self.view as it makes my app crash with

> exc_bad_access

thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, we can make this work for sure. In your code above, you show 'self.view', which I believe is the view under the modal view. Do you have a reference to the modal view, and if so, did you try to just show it there (.. showInView:modalViewController.view]) ?

Comment: hi @DavidH, thanks, i have tried,  [popupQuery showInView:self.modalViewController.view]; but i get another crash, 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil',, thanks

Comment: So create a small demo app - a single viewController template. Define another viewController subclass, add it as a modal view, and provide some way to message your first VC to tell it to pop the action sheet (this could be a button on the modal view that messages the other VC). Get it to fail as your big app is failing. Zip that up, put on dropbox, and update your Question with that info. For sure me or others can find the problem in a few minutes. This for sure should work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't fully read your response above (was moving around due to commute). So this is nil: self.modalViewController.view. Well that's a huge problem now isn't it? I'm guessing modalViewController is nil but its view property might be nil too. Fix that and your problem may be solved.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem?